# Removing all but latest of specific files in a folder

Tags: python-3.x

I have a folder where three specific files end up, two of the three files get overwritten and one stacks as the date and time are included in the file name.

1. File 1: Response.csv
2. File 2: idle.csv
3. File 3: yyyymmdd_EMSRP_yyymmdd_hhmmss.csv

I currently have the following working code:

```
import os

source_folder = 'E:/idle/'

def latestFile():
    EMSRP_List = []
    for somefile in os.listdir(source_folder):

        if (somefile.startswith('20')):
            EMSRP_List.append(source_folder+somefile)

    EMSRP_List.sort()
    #print(len(EMSRP_List))
    if len(EMSRP_List) > 1:
        for file in EMSRP_List[:-1]:
            os.remove(file)
    #print(EMSRP_List)

def main():

   latestFile() 

if __name__== "__main__":
    main()
```

This won't work indefinitely, is there a better way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: What is your end goal?

Comment: To remove non latest files without depending on the filename of the file. Can the first two be excluded and then delete the File 3 files by there creation date?

Comment: I have a solution that still depends on the filename (at least the format of your EMSRP files) but slightly more efficient. If it is acceptable, I can share the answer. I don't want the community to point out - "That is not what the OP asked for".

Comment: Yeah please, if its more efficient I'll still learn something!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just my idea. I am expecting better alternatives from more experienced programmers.

I create an excluded list of files which I remove from the list first. Then I get the `max` of file_list. If the pattern of the filename matches whatever you have shared, then max returns the latest of your EMSRP file.

```
import os
source_folder = 'E:/idle/'

file_list = os.listdir(source_folder)
exclude_files = ['Response.csv', 'idle.csv']
file_list = [x for x in file_list if x not in exclude_files]
latest_file = max(file_list)
file_list.remove(latest_file)

for file in file_list:
    os.remove(source_folder + file)
```

Comment: This is much better than what I had, never thought to exclude files like that. Thanks!